# Installing Xubuntu. Should I use repositories or install directly from the xubuntu disc image?

Tags: xubuntu

I am considering two options for installing Xubuntu 14.04.1 on my PC. I can install Ubuntu using [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) disc image, and then use the repositories to install the Xubuntu desktop.

The other option is to install Xubuntu using [this](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) disc image directly.

What are the differences between these two paths to getting the Xubuntu desktop on my PC? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Why the close vote? Please leave a comment.

Comment: Someone said that this is primarily opinion-based...which, in my opinion, it is.

Comment: @saiarcot895 I am asking about the differences between the two approaches. That's not an opinion. The difference is a factual thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off with instaling Xubuntu. Althoug they share the same base (Ubuntu), Xubuntu is more clean and you'll get only the packages you need.

For example:

1 - Installing Ubuntu and then installing XFCE (Xubuntu), you'll end up with a lot of packages and customizations that you don't want or need.

2 - Installing Xubuntu will get you a clean, strimmed version of Xubuntu, wich is what you need.

3 - There's a team dedicated to Xubuntu that's dedicated to this customized distro, and therefore you will have a space more dedicated for the DE you want.

If later you decide do install something else (Gnome, Unity, etc) you still can do it, because Xubuntu is Ubuntu.

Comment: Two questions: 1) By LxUbuntu you mean Xubuntu?, 2) If I install Xubuntu, will I still get all the drivers I need? (The PC has no internet connection)

Comment: 1) Yes, i already fixed that. 2) If you install Xubuntu, you'll get  the same drivers as Ubuntu, the only difference is the DE

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the image found on Xubuntu's site. The main different between the two flavors is the desktop environment, and accessory program selection. Xubuntu uses a lightweight desktop environment called Xcfe and Ubuntu uses Unity. In addition, all flavors of Ubuntu use the same repository for downloading updates, so the same set of packages is available regardless of which flavor you have installed.

- [Lubuntu (LXDE Desktop)](http://lubuntu.net/)
- [Xubuntu (Xcfe Desktop)](http://xubuntu.org/)
- [About Unity](https://unity.ubuntu.com/about/)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be confusion about Xubuntu vs Lubuntu. Both of these are official Ubuntu variations, so after the install is complete, you will be using the same Ubuntu repositories as if you installed Ubuntu then used the repositories to install another desktop environment.

The difference is that:

Xubuntu uses XFCE - http://xubuntu.org/

Lubuntu uses LXDE - http://lubuntu.net/

When you install Xubuntu or Lubuntu, you don't have to deal with resetting the default environment, as you would if you installed through the repositories.